# How to use patchcmd to insert \clearpage before \chapter to avoid breaking page

Tags: page-breaking, etoolbox

I want my document to not start new pages when there is a new chapter.
My code is the following:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\chapter}{\clearpage}{}{}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Preliminary}
first chapter

\chapter{Discussion}
second chapter

{\let \clearpage \relax\chapter{Advanced}}
final chapter
\end{document}
```

This code will start new pages for the first and second chapters but not for the third one.

Why is my \patchcmd not working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you have a syntax error in the `\patchcmd` line, because you're missing a brace pair:

```
\patchcmd{<macro>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
```

This has no consequences in this case, because the patch fails, so `\begin` that was absorbed as the fifth argument is delivered because of the failure.

Main reason: the `\chapter` macro has no `\clearpage` in its replacement text, which is

```
\scr@startchapter{chapter}
```

and it is `\scr@startchapter` that must be patched

```
% scrbook.cls, line 4030:
\newcommand*{\scr@startchapter}[1]{%
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \scr@ifundefinedorrelax{#1pagestyle}{}{%
    \ifstr{#1pagestyle}{}{}{%
      \thispagestyle{\@nameuse{#1pagestyle}}%
    }%
  }%
  \global\@topnum\z@
  \@afterindentfalse
  \expandafter\SecDef\csname @#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname @s#1\endcsname
}
```

Always check the meaning of a macro, before trying to patch it.

You probably want to remove both `\cleardoublepage` and `\clearpage`, so

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\scr@startchapter}
  {\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}% search
  {}% replace
  {}{\ddt}
\makeatother
```

I find it convenient to add something like `\ddt`, which will warn about failure with `Undefined control sequence \ddt`. When I'm sure the patch succeeds, I remove it.

Answer (score 11):

With a KOMA-Script class you can use `\RedeclareSectionCommand` to set `style=section` for the chapter headings. So there is no need to patch anything.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}[2015/10/03]

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  style=section,
  indent=0pt
]{chapter}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Preliminary}
first chapter
\chapter{Discussion}
second chapter
\chapter{Advanced}
final chapter
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution. One need to patch `\scr@startchapter`

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\if@openright
\patchcmd{\scr@startchapter}{\cleardoublepage}{}{}{}
\else
\patchcmd{\scr@startchapter}{\clearpage}{}{}{}
\fi
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\chapter{Preliminary}
first chapter

\chapter{Discussion}
second chapter

\end{document}
```